# Geopandas .plotting() not working with matplotlib.pyplot: isintance() arg2 must be type or tuple of types

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, geopandas

using `matplotlib===3.5.1 && geopandas===0.9.0`

When running the following command:

```py
pos = Figure(figsize=PAGE_DIMS,tight_layout=LAYOUT_DICT)

pos.suptitle("Pos", x=1, y=4, color='g')

b_pos = pos.add_gridspec(3, 9)

ax = pos.add_subplot(b_pos[0, 1:4])

world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('file_name'))

world.plot(ax=ax, color='lightblue', edgecolor='black')
```

I am getting the below error

```py
File "~/python3.8/dist-packages/geopandas/plotting.py", line 925, in __call__
    return plot_dataframe(data, *args, **kwargs)
File "~/python3.8/dist-packages/geopandas/plotting.py", line 689, in plot_dataframe
    return plot_series(
File "~/python3.8/dist-packages/geopandas/plotting.py", line 467, in plot_series
    plt.draw()
File "~/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 952, in draw
    gcf().canvas.draw_idle()
File "~/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 846, in gcf
    return figure()
File "~/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 751, in figure
    if isinstance(num, Figure):
Type: <class 'TypeError'>, Obj: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types, TB: <traceback object at XXXXXXXXX>
```

I tried downgrading libraries to no avail. Also not sure if there is an arg/kwarg I can pass to get around this issue.

Edit: I have discovered exactly where the exception is getting tripped: in matplotlib.pyplot.figure, the function appears as so, on line 665 in matplotlib/pyplot.py :

```
def figure(num=None,figsize=None,dpi=None,facecolor=None, edgecolor=None, frameon=True, FigureClass=Figure, clear=False,**kwargs):

    if isinstance(num, Figure):
        if num.canvas.manager is None:
            raise ValueError("The passed figure is not managed by pyplot")
        _pylab_helpers.Gcf.set_active(num.canvas.manager)
        return num
```

When I comment this block out, I am getting my desired output. Perhaps I'm missing a kwarg?

Comment: can you show us the full traceback? It looks like this is missing the top

Comment: also geopandas' current version is 0.11 - 0.9 is over a year old. Have you tried upgrading?

Comment: also - can you show all the code? how do you define `ax`?

Comment: apologies for the insufficient info. I added the requested details above. I tried upgrading and downgrading everything: geopandas, matplotlib, pandas, with no luck.

Above I have also detailed the exact spot where the exception occurs

Comment: thanks for the updates! But we really need the *full traceback*. It should start with `Traceback (most recent call last)`. See [this guide](//realpython.com/python-traceback). also it would be really helpful if you could provide a [mre] - it's hard to debug class conflicts if we don't see your imports, etc. If this really is a bug, we'll need a full MRE that we can execute, so whatever you can do to provide context is helpful! thanks! :)